# Android Wait for startBluetoothSco SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED

Tags: android, bluetooth, wait, text-to-speech

I'm having a problem with startBluetoothSco not connecting quick enough.  How do I wait do get the SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED return value then continue on to having my message read aloud.  By the time the connected state is returned I have already read half the message aloud.  If I do a sleep then the main activity stalls and nothing happens.  As you can tell I'm kind of a beginner in Android.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is a little old but I thought I would answer anyway since I had the same problem.

Setup a receiver:

```
ScoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1) ==
            AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED) {

            // SCO now connected
        }
    }
};
```

Then create an IntentFilter and register receiver

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);

this.registerReceiver(ScoReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Then start SCO

```
am = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
am.startBluetoothSco();
```

When your done using the SCO

```
am.stopBluetoothSco();
```

Comment: I have the same exact code as yours but i always get disconnected , any reason please ??

Comment: This is VERY old! But, I'm not sure what you are asking. My code doesn't do anything until the state becomes connected. If you are saying that you get an unknown disconnect after being connected, that is beyond the scope of my code. If you never get a state connected, that is also beyond the scope of my code. This will be down to your BT device (IOW hardware issue)

Comment: Yes basically i have the same exact code , with bluetooth headsets already connected but it always goes to the disconnected block .. i agree i think it is hardware problem , i need to check on different headsets , Thank you